# How to force app uninstall in order to update?

Tags: java, android, certificate, google-play, code-signing

I did a mistake that apparently can be solved only by uninstalling and then installing my app again.

I delivered a message to the users, but no-one seems to uninstall it.

AFAIK, if I change the certificate file, the play store won't let me upload the application, and
obviously I don't want to upload a new app.

Is there a way to force uninstall in order to update?

Thanks!

Comment: What was the mistake and why can't you fix it with an updated version?

Comment: I added a `SharedUserId` in the manifest and forgotten to remove it before uploading to the market. It causes `SharedPreferences` to be unsaved

Comment: @ Android Joker, are you sure that the root cause is what you think it is?  Is there any chance that it's NOT a SharedUserId problem?

Comment: I don't understand. What does uninstall do that you can't fix in code in the new version?

Comment: @full.stack.ex Yes, i'm sure. I remember I read somewhere that it can cause problems, and also, when you set SharedUserId is supposed to be used in order to share preferences between several apps, so it connected to SharedPreferences...
and Squonk, I have no idea... It just seems to work

Comment: How about finding the piece you've read?  Chances are, there is also a solution there.  Also, if that's indeed the case, would using non-default shared preferences instead of default help you avoid the uninstallation?

Comment: It's not the piece I read, but it is also good:
http://java-hamster.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/androids-shareduserid.html

Seems like I have no choice...

Comment: @full.stack.ex : Just spent the last 10 minutes reading these two 'Open Issues'... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1227  and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14074 It does look like a serious problem with no workaround which would suit the OP.

Comment: @AndroidJoker : Unfortunately it looks like there's no fix. Sorry.

Comment: Attempting lateral thinking, a couple crazy ideas. 1) data dir unavailable => show a reinstall message, use external storage ; 2) [insane :)] nest 3 apks into each other: the outermost one discovers the problem and suggests to reinstall,  installs the next one. That removes the original and installs a replacement. You know your app better

Comment: - so you may devise some alternatives

Answer (score 3):

There's no killswitch to remotely force uninstalls (that'd be a security nightmare).  What you *can* do is publish a fixed version on Google Play, and wait for users to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you but i had the same problem. The solution for me is that i check the app version every time the user opens it and compare it with a version code stored on apache server (in a checkversion.php file).
If versions doesn't match, i show a not cancelable dialog that ask the user to go to market and download the update.

Here is an example (keep in mind that i use [Volley library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to handle connections):

```
    public class UpdateManager {

        private Activity ac;
        private HashMap<String,String> params;

        public UpdateManager(Activity ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        public void checkForUpdates() {
            Log.d("UpdateManager","checkForUpdates() - Started...");

            params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("request","checkforupdates");
            try {
                params.put("versioncode", String.valueOf(ac.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ac.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode));
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (Helper.isInternetAvailable(ac)) { //this is a class i made to check internet connection availability
                checkAppVersion();
            } else { Log.d("UpdateManager","CheckForUpdates(): Impossible to update version due to lack of connection"); }
        }

        private void checkAppVersion() {
            Log.d("UpdateManager","checkAppVersion() - Request started...");

            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest("http://yourserver/checkappversion.php", new JSONObject(params),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response != null && response.has("result")) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("UpdateManager","checkAppVersion() - Request finished - Response: "+response.getString("result"));
                            if (response.getString("result").matches("updaterequested")) { //Update requested. Show the relative dialog
                                Log.d("UpdateManager","Update requested");

                                askUserForUpdate();
                            }
                            else if (response.getString("result").matches("current")) { //Same version. Do nothing 
                                Log.d("UpdateManager","Version is up to date");
                            }
                            else if (response.getString("result").matches("error")) { //You can return an error message if error occurred on server
                                Log.d("UpdateManager","checkappversion Error - "+response.getString("error"));
                            }

                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("UpdateManager","Volley Error - "+error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            ConnectionController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
        }

        public void askUserForUpdate() {
            final Dialog diag = new Dialog(ac);
            diag.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            diag.setContentView(R.layout.updatemanager_requestupdate_dialog);
            diag.setCancelable(false);
            diag.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            TextView t = (TextView)diag.findViewById(R.id.requestupdate_dialog_main_text);
            ImageView im_ok = (ImageView)diag.findViewById(R.id.requestupdate_dialog_ok);
            ImageView im_canc = (ImageView)diag.findViewById(R.id.requestupdate_dialog_canc);
            t.setText(ac.getResources().getString(R.string.update_manager_askuserforupdate));
            im_canc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    diag.dismiss();
                    ac.finish();
                }
            });
            im_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ac.getPackageName()));
                    diag.dismiss();
                    ac.startActivity(intent);
                    ac.finish();
                }
            });
            diag.show();
        }
    }
```

You can then use it when your main activity (or maybe login activity) starts like this:

```
     UpdateManager updateManager = new UpdateManager(MainActivity.this); //i assume MainActicity as the calling activity
     updateManager.checkForUpdates();
```

Obviously this has to be implemented into the application code so, the first time, you have to rely only on the user to manually upgrade it. But this can help if you have the same problem in the future.

This is an extract from my personal code so you have to rearrange it to your needings. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Users should be able to go to `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications` and select the application to be removed.  I've never seen a case where the application can't be removed this way, except in the case of built-in applications which require a rooted device to remove.

Comment: I said I want it to be removed automatically

Comment: Oh, in that case you're out of luck.  Only applications signed with Google's own signing key can install and uninstall applications.  All you can do is place updated versions on the android market and hope users checked the "automatic upgrade" feature for the app.  Or have them use rooted phones.